# How to find calls for hashing handshaking messages in OpenSSL library?

Tags: c, openssl, tls1.3

I am finding the procedures inside OpenSSL library, which update a running hash during TLS 1.3 handshaking (all handshaking messages form that hash).
 To do this I have set breakpoint inside OpenSSL hashing function (in `digest.c`), waiting for them to be called (a program, used to trace - `s_client`):

```
int EVP_DigestUpdate(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx, const void *data, size_t count) {
... // here breakpoint was set in the original openssl-implementation of this function
}
```

But looking which messages are passed in `data` and hashed inside (I have seen memory blocks referred by `data`) I have not found any callers that wanted to hash ServelHello/ClientHello.
Could you help me - how can I find the code lines, which call hashing of handshake messages inside OpenSSL?

Comment: I have found it. The question is closed.